# Get the first pandas DataFrame's column?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to calculate `std` of my first `prices` DataFrame's column.

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

def std(returns):
    return pd.DataFrame(returns.std(axis=0, ddof=0))

prices = pd.DataFrame([[-0.33333333, -0.25343423, -0.1666666667],
                       [+0.23432323, +0.14285714, -0.0769230769],
                       [+0.42857143, +0.07692308, +0.1818181818]])

print(std(prices.ix[:,0]))
```

When I run it, i get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\*****\Documents\******\******\****.py", line 12, in <module>
    print(std(prices.ix[:,0]))
  File "C:\Users\*****\Documents\******\******\****.py", line 10, in std
    return pd.DataFrame(returns.std(axis=0, ddof=0))
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 453, in __init__
    raise PandasError('DataFrame constructor not properly called!')
pandas.core.common.PandasError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!
```

**How can I fix that?**

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a closer look at what is going in in your code:

```
>>> prices.ix[:,0]
0   -0.333333
1    0.234323
2    0.428571

>>> prices.ix[:,0].std(axis=0, ddof=0)
0.32325861621668445
```

So you are calling the DataFrame constructor like this:

```
pd.DataFrame(0.32325861621668445)
```

The constructor has no idea what to do with single float parameter. It needs some kind of sequence or iterable. Maybe what you what is this:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame([0.32325861621668445])
          0
0  0.323259
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be as simple as this:

```
In [0]: prices[0].std()

Out[0]: 0.39590933234452624
```

Columns of `DataFrames` are `Series`. You can call `Series` methods on them directly.